# how to prove $\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{n}{n^3+1}=0$ using definition of limits?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

> $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{n}{n^3+1}=0$$

I know that to prove this i have to find a $N \in \Bbb N$

$\forall   \epsilon>0$ s.t

if $n>N $ then $|\frac{n}{n^3+1}-0|< \epsilon$ i tried it some wayes but i couldnt find an answer

Comment: limit for $x\rightarrow 0$ or for $n \rightarrow 0$ ?

Comment: sorry $n \to \infty$

Comment: yeah sorry I made it wrong in my comment as well ahah

Comment: Notice that $\frac{n}{n^3+1}\leq \frac{n}{n^3} = \frac{1}{n^2} \leq \frac{1}{n}$. Then just use the Archimedian property.

Comment: what ways have you tried. we may assume n is positive so   n/(n^3 + 1)| < epsilon requires n  > f(epsilon) ought to be solvable.

Comment: @fleablood i have given an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\left| \frac { n }{ n^{ 3 }+1 } -0 \right| <\varepsilon \quad \left| \frac { n }{ n^{ 3 }+1 }  \right| <\left| \frac { n }{ { n }^{ 3 } }  \right| =\frac { 1 }{ { n }^{ 2 } } <\varepsilon $$ this means $$n>\frac { 1 }{ \sqrt { \varepsilon  }  } $$  where ${ n }_{ \varepsilon  }=\frac { 1 }{ \sqrt { \varepsilon  }  } $

so

> $$\forall \varepsilon >0,\exists { n }_{ \varepsilon  }\epsilon N,n> { n }_{ \varepsilon  }\quad \left| \frac { n }{ n^{ 3 }+1 }  \right| <\varepsilon $$

Comment: (Do you want to use $\lceil \frac{1}{\sqrt{\epsilon}} \rceil$ ?)

Comment: no used a floor function

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I don't think $n\ge \lfloor\frac{1}{\sqrt{\epsilon}}\rfloor\implies n>\frac{1}{\sqrt{\epsilon}}$.

Comment: thank you,you are probably right,i should check it again

Comment: It's a minor point, since you can either change to the ceiling function, or just change to $n>n_{\epsilon}$ instead of $n\ge n_{\epsilon}$

Comment: @user84413 thanks again)

Answer (score 3):

Using that $n\leq n^2$ and that $0\leq 1$ we get

$$\frac{n}{n^3+1}\leq \frac{n^2}{n^3+1}\leq \frac{n^2}{n^3}=\frac{1}{n}$$

Answer (score 0):

I got an answer.

$|\frac{n}{n^3+1}|<\frac{1}{n}$ I choose $N=\lceil\frac{1}{\epsilon} \rceil$

$\forall \epsilon>0$ if $n>N \Rightarrow n>\lceil\frac{1}{\epsilon} \rceil>\frac{1}{\epsilon} \Rightarrow \epsilon>\frac{1}{n}>\frac{n}{n^3+1}>|\frac{n}{n^3+1}-0|$

Answer (score -1):

I see it this way. You can divide both numerator and denominator by n to get

lim(n-->inf) 1/(n^2+1/n)

1/n --> 0 in the denominator, so the trend would be 1/n^2, which as n approaches infinity, the limit approaches 0.

Comment: I'm curious why my solution is receiving bad reviews. What's wrong with my method of solution? Anybody... explain your negative vote.

Comment: Where did you use any $\epsilon$s? The question is about proving this from the $\epsilon-N$ definition of convergence. You never address this.